# Hydration of alkenes: is phosphoric acid a gas at these temperatures?

Tags: organic-chemistry

> Ethene is mixed with steam and passed over a catalyst consisting of solid silicon dioxide coated with phosphoric(V) acid. The temperature used is 300°C and the pressure is about 60 to 70 atmospheres.

Source: https://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/catalysis/hydrate.html

But isn't phosphoric acid vapourized at this temperature? I know that phosphoric acid is a gas at 158°C, assuming atmospheric pressure. Perhaps the high temperature increases the boiling point, so that phosphoric acid remains an liquid at this temperature?

Comment: Sloppy writing of that "chemguide" (is that a reputable source?). What they mean is silicon dioxide that is acidic on the surface because it was *treated* with phosphoric acid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Phosphoric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphoric_acid) definitely is not a gas at $\pu{158 ^{\circ}C}$. It undergoes boiling decomposition at $\pu{212^{\circ}C}$, releasing water and condensating to pyrophosphoric acid
$\ce{2 H3PO4 -> H2O + H4P2O7}$ and eventually higher polyphosphoric acids.

$[\ce{\bond{-}O-P(=O)(OH)\bond{-}}]_n$

Such condensation progressively occurs even at room temperature if concentration of phosphoric acid is higher than 85% (about equimolar acid:water ratio) what is the reason the commercial product has this concentration.

Being initially coated by phosphoric acid does not mean phosphoric acid is present  at operational conditions. It would be already polyphosphoric acid.